# ImportError: No module named 'selenium' in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have installed all the file and packages like python, pip, selenium and i am running a python code in PyCharm, but it is still showing me this error whenever i run my code.

**Error showing while running python file.**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/aman.k/PycharmProjects/SeleniumScripts/MyFirstSeleniumScript.py",
>   line 3, in  import webdriver ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'webdriver'

**Code running environment:**

- Windows OS 8.1
- Python 3.7.2
- pip 19.0.2

**Here is my code which i am trying to run.**

[image]

Comment: in terminal do `pip install webdriver`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From your screenshot, I can see that selenium is not installed. Please follow the next step:

**1st solution:**

> File -> Settings -> Inside your project's name -> Project Interpreter
>   -> click on "+" button -> search for selenium (**current version 3.141.0**) -> click on install -> restart PyCharm.

**2nd solution:**

> Or click on the selenium word from the first line (from the import)
>   and wait until a solution will be shown. The solution will say install
>   selenium package. Press on it and you are done.

**Screenshot for solution 2:**

[image]

**3rd solution:**

> If you have already installed the selenium then you need to install
>   webdirver. Follow the following screenshot to solve it.

**Screenshot for 3rd solution:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution, i tried first one and it worked for me but it started throwing me another Error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aman.k/PycharmProjects/SeleniumScripts/MyFirstSeleniumScript.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.chrome("E:\\Work\\workspace\\chromedriver.exe")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Comment: @AmanKumar make a new question and insert a screenshot so to understand what your problem is :) After the question gives me here the link so to see it. Because is something completely different and can not be in the same question :)

Comment: Okay @dpap thank you for your guidance, i will create a new question for that problem and also thank you for the helping me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Aman Kumar paste here the link of your new question so that I will see it and help you. Anytime :)

Comment: Thank you @dpap Your solution really helped me to solve my problem very easily, regarding my previous question i was unable to get the path of chrome driver and i have reinstalled the chrome driver in my system and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Pychram can use more than one environment for running your project. I guess you are using a different environment in which you have installed tools. Change the env by going

File > Settings > Prefrences > Project Interpreter.

Either change that to the local env or click + button below the window and add that package to current env.

Answer (score 0):

You may have it installed in a different env and running pycharm from a different env. The best solution is to go to file then setting then your project and python interpreter. Click on the small + sign and search pycharm and finally click on install to install it. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, but i was unable to install packages so i tried to change the interpreter and that too failed so i deleted the existing venv and then it automatically selected the default python, and the problem was solved.
I don't know it is the right way or not but it was the only way i found.